# how Do I solve a problem where modules don’t get imported although I installed it?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to use the module pyautogui but when I import it,python says no module named pyautogui even though I installed it on command prompt

Comment: Is it in the output of `python -m pip freeze` ?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting might be because you are installing it on python 2 instead of python 3.
Try running pip3 install pyautogui

Comment: How could you possibly know this from what OP provided? This would be better as a comment.